# derivative of the exponential integral

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, matlab

I have one function that is defined:

$$E_x(f)=\int K_\sigma(y-x) \cdot e^{-a\cdot f(y)} \, dy$$

where $y$ is neighboor points of $x$; $f(y)$ is a function of $y$; and $a$ is constant.

I want to take  want to calculate derivative of this function with respect to $a$. Could you help me implement it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}E_x(f)=-\int f(y) K_\sigma(y-x)\cdot e^{-a\cdot f(y)}dy
$$

see [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

Comment: Thank you. Do you express it by convolution formular such as ∫f(y)Kσ(y−x)dy=f*K?

Comment: But how about e^{−a⋅f(y)} term? That mean ∫f(y)Kσ(y−x)⋅e^{−a⋅f(y)}dy=f*K*...?

Comment: You are making a derivative with respect to a parameter $a$ which is not involved in convolution. Hence you simply differentiate with respect to $a$.

Comment: So we cannot express convolution from your result. Is it right? Thank you

Comment: You can write it as $g * K_\sigma$ with $g(x) = -f(x) e^{-af(x)}$